# Is there any native way to access Office 365 user calendar and shared calendars?

Tags: office365, imap, .net-4.6

I am developing an application that normally would read and write all calendars in an Office 365 tenant. This is straightforward with app-permissions.
But the client decided not to allow this scenario, neither delegated permissions. They want a solution where there is no any app registration needed in the Azure AD (don't ask me why). They want to share all affected calendars with a dedicated user and I should use non-REST API methods to read and write those shared calendars.

So I am looking for any native way. I am thinking about IMAP, as Outlook is using this protocol to connect. But only knowing the email address, how can I discover the server to connect to?

Supposing I can get that information, or I can somehow avoid relying on this, can anyone suggest me an IMAP library for .NET 4+ (4.6+ preferably) that is capable of handling calendars. Commercially supported(!) library suggestions are also welcome.

(Note: thanks, I can google for myself, I would appreciate the first-hand experience :) )

Thank you.

Comment: Calendars are not an IMAP feature.

Comment: Thank you. Then what is Outlook using?

Comment: Windows outlook: MAPI;  Mac Outlook: EWS.

Comment: Ok, then Windows Outlook is still getting Calendar with MAPI. Doesn't it?

Comment: Windows Outlook, in general, uses MAPI for everything.  It's the native protocol for it.

Comment: @Max. First, you say that Calendar is not MAPI feature, then you say that Outlook Windows is using MAPI to reach the calendar. This means that calendars can be reached with MAPI. Thus my question stays.

Comment: IMAP != MAPI.  You asked about IMAP: calendars are not an IMAP feature.  Calendars are a MAPI feature.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this. I wasn't aware of the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, Office365 has Exchange server under the hood, that supports Exchange Web Services. EWS does exactly what I need, although it is a little bit slower.